# JQuery - Navigation Menu slideUp / slideDown transitioning

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, menubar, transition

Trying to have a smooth navigation bar that has several buttons, and then when clicked each button drops down a little div with the relevant information.

However, I am having problems getting it to work right when lets say you click on a button, it starts opening the div, then you click on another button, it has some problems loading the right content into the universal div used to display the button's content.

Whats the best way to fix it so that if you start to open a div from one button then click another one real quick, it will hide/stop the first attempt and immediately go to the 2nd? Right now if I do that, it will not load the content properly as the .empty() gets executed after the new div is starting to display.

Right now I just use a setTimeout function to delay it, but its not working right.

*NOTE - I use .on instead of just .click due the menu being dynamically created depending on what page the user is on. This works just find in binding the click event.

```
//CONTROL BAR 
    //CLICK OFF OF FORMS
    $(document).on('click','.clear_overlay, .control_bar',function(){
        hideForm();
    });
    //SHOW FORM
    $(document).on('click','.control_bar li.button',function(){
        //CHECK IF CURRENTLY OPEN
        if(!$(this).hasClass('pressed')){
            var form = this;
            setTimeout(function(){showForm(form)},210);
        }
    });

    //SHOW FORM
    function showForm(form){
        var str = $(form).attr('class').split(' ');
        var cl = str[0];
        var id = $(form).attr('id');
        var x = $(form).position().left;
        var y = $(form).position().top;
        x += 230;
        y += 50;
        $('.clear_overlay').show();
        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        $('.control_bar_form').load('_forms/'+cl+'.php',function(){
            $('.control_bar_form').find('.button_submit').attr('id',id);
            $('.control_bar_form').css({ "left": x, "top":y });
            $('.control_bar_form').slideToggle(200);
            $(form).addClass('pressed');
        });
    }
    function hideForm(){
        $('.clear_overlay').hide();
        $('body').css('overflow','auto');
        $('.control_bar_form').slideUp(200,function(){
            $('.control_bar li').removeClass('pressed');
            $('.control_bar_form').empty().css('width','auto');
            $('.control_bar_form :input[type="text"]').val('');
            $('.control_bar_form :input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
            $('.clear_overlay').hide();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to the click event all wrong. This is how you connect:

```
$('.control_bar li.button').click(function(){
//Stuff here
});
```

Comment: No that works just fine. I have to do it using .on because the content of the navigation menu is dynamically created. So using the normal .click function will not be binded.

Comment: O ok, To be honest I don't see any issues. Try running it in Safari or FF and clicking 'Inspect Element' and look at the error. Very helpful.

Comment: There is no actual error. The error is that since the 'slideUp' hasn't finished when the 'slideDown' is happening, the .empty() function that is called in the slideUp callback, executes AFTER the slideDown (and loading of new content) of the other div is happening, so the contents of the new div get emptied as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for this error. Changing the slideUp time to 1 (i.e. slideUp(1)) allows a faster execution of the .empty() call and thus allows the new content to be loaded.

I would still like a better solution if possible. But this does work for now.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that one part of your script is not sufficiently aware of the state another part is operating on. That means you need to add some variable explaining the state and make sure that variable is visible to the part of the script that needs to check the state. Something like

var isOpening=false;

which is then set to true in the showForm() function and back to false in its last callback. The hideForm() function should check the value of this variable and just return if it is true.